# referencing consecutive values from a table in excel to a new sheet every 3 rows

Tags: excel

For example:

Sheet 1, Table 1  ----> Sheet 2

**Column A**      **Column A**

A1 Text A        A1 Text A

A2 Text B        A2 *blank*

A3 Text C        A3 *blank*

A4 Text D        A4 Text B

and so on...

is there a formula that i can autofill sheet 2 with?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If *Sheet1* is like:

[image]

The in *Sheet2* cell **A1** enter:

```
=IF(MOD(ROWS($1:1),3)=1,INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,ROUNDUP(ROW()/3,0)),"")
```

and copy downward:

[image]